# Dynamically build accordion with *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

While building an accordion I was able to dynamically get accordion items. The problem now is that they all open at the same time. Is it possible to open them one by one based on ID?

This is my code:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div *ngFor="let task of tasks" class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            {{task.name}}
        </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                {{task.description}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I assume the problem is that "collapseOne" is hard-coded but I can't find the solution online.

Comment: You can get the index with ngFor and then add that to the id string

Answer (score 2):

I haven't experience with accordion. But judging by the code, it seems you need to bind individual IDs to each item. You could try to use the [`index`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) local variable of the `*ngFor` directive.

```html
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div *ngFor="let task of tasks; let i=index" class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button 
        class="accordion-button" 
        type="button" 
        data-bs-toggle="collapse{{i}}" 
        data-bs-target="#collapseOne{{i}}"
        aria-expanded="true"
        aria-controls="collapseOne{{i}}"
      >
        {{task.name}}
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div 
      id="collapseOne{{i}}" 
      class="accordion-collapse collapse show" 
      aria-labelledby="headingOne"
      data-bs-parent="#accordionExample"
    >
      <div class="accordion-body">
        {{task.description}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```